# Undefined variable error while performing numerical integration in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

For a matlab question, I need to integrate 
`fun2 = @(x) 1/(sigma2*(2*pi)^(.5))*exp(-.5*((x-xbar2)/sigma2)^2)`, 
where `sigma2=50`, `xbar2=1500`.

The area under the curve should be 0.05, so I set it up as `solve(integrate(fun2,-inf,u)==.05,u)` but I get the error "Undefined function or variable 'u'."

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Which one are you trying to do: symbolic integration or numeric integration (i.e. you want a function or a number as result)?

Comment: To clarify, this is a gaussian distribution, and I know that u=1417.76 by solving in Mathematica.  I am looking for a type of solve code that will tell me what the upper limit of integration, u, is based on knowledge of the solution, 0.05

Comment: CST-Link, I am looking for a numerical answer.  I can do it in other programs, just not sure how in Matlab.

Comment: what is `integrate`??

Answer (score 1):

So here we go:

```
syms x u
fun = int(1./(50.*(2.*pi).^(.5)).*exp(-.5.*((x-1500)./50).^2),-Inf,u) - .05;
double(solve(fun,u))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't require the symbolic toolbox; Matlab's standard [root-finding algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm):

```
>> f = @(u) quadgk(fun2, -inf,u) - 0.05;
>> fzero(f,xbar2)

ans =

     1.417757318652430e+003
```

(I used `quadgk` because I'm on R2010 which doesn't have `integrate`. It's the same thing anyway).

The root finding algorithm `fzero` finds the zero-passages of the anonymous function `f`, which is nothing but your original `fun2` minus the value you want -- which passes through zero exactly when the value of the original integral reaches your chosen value.

Comment: I was going with the same procedure but you were posting faster :)